# Kinect device not found in device manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, kinect, kinect-sdk

When i go to my device manager i can't see my kinect device. I
downloaded the kinect SDK 1.6.

[image: Installed SDK]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Kinect for Windows Device" that is supposed to show up there is the motor in the base of the Kinect, used for tilting the device up and down. While theoretically you don't need it, its absence in the Device Manager may be a curiosity that heralds trouble.

On two occasions where I and a friend have had similar problems (I was missing the Camera, and he was missing the Audio Array), we found the power plug to be the culprit. Make sure everything is connected properly. Try moving to a different the USB port and/or restarting the computer.

That said, what appears in the Device Manager does depend on your specific configuration. My Device Manager, on Win 8 x64 with the SDK 1.6 and an X-box Kinect, shows 4 nodes: the three that you have, plus the "Kinect for Windows Device." ['Meet the Kinect' by Kean, Hall and Kerry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238887) says you would have a "Microsoft Kinect Device", a "Microsoft Kinect Camera" and a "Microsoft Kinect Audio Array Control;" no "Security Control." [Webb and Ashley's 'Beginning Kinect Programming...'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430241047) shows the three nodes that you have as the correct ones, plus a "Kinect USB Audio" node under "Sound, video and game controllers."

So really, if your device works, don't worry.

Comment: Are you sure that device line is still listed on your system (using the official SDK)?  I've checked several of our systems with Kinects connected and only ever see the 3 lines listed in the question.

Comment: Phew!  Awesome information!  I was starting to get worried myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is as it should be.  You have the audio array listed and the cameras, which is all the Kinect is... a microphone and a pair of cameras.  All the other "magic" is done on the software end, within the SDK.

You are not missing anything and should be able to develop applications with the Kinect.